# How can i have common actions for multiple reducers using createSlice

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-toolkit

In old way of redux we could create reducer like this - different action types but same action:

```js
export default function authReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case AUTH_ERROR:
    case LOGIN_FAIL:
    case LOGOUT_SUCCESS:
    case REGISTER_FAIL:
      localStorage.removeItem("xts0");
      return {
        ...state,
        token: null,
        user: null,
        isAuthenticated: false,
        isLoading: false,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

How can I do the same with `createSlice` utility?

```js
const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: "auth",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    authError(state, action){},
    loginFail(state, action){},
    and so on
  }
})
```

Comment: You are looking for `extraReducers`: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createslice#the-extrareducers-builder-callback-notation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a single reducer function that applies the state update logic.

```js
const resetAuth = (state, action) => {
  localStorage.removeItem("xts0");
  return initialState;
};
```

If `authSlice` is creating these actions then use the same reducer function for each action:

```js
const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: "auth",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    authError: resetAuth,
    loginFail: resetAuth,
    // ... and so on
  },
});
```

If all these actions already exist and the `authSlice` just needs to also handle them, then use the `extraReducers` property. This is for defining reducer cases for external (*to the slice*) actions.

```js
const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: "auth",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    ...
  },
  extraReducers: builder => {
    builder
      .addCase(authError, resetAuth)
      .addCase(loginFail, resetAuth)
      // ... and so on
  },
});
```

In the above I'm assuming that all the actions are Redux-Toolkit actions (*e.g. created in other slices or using `createAction`*). If they are "legacy" Redux actions, then I believe you'll likely need to specify the `type` property for the case, e.g. `.addCase(authError.type, resetAuth)`.

Furthermore, to make the code a little more ***DRY*** you can use a [Matcher](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/matching-utilities#using-matchers-to-reduce-code-complexity-duplication-and-boilerplate) to reduce the amount of code you write.

Example:

```js
import { isAnyOf } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: "auth",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    ...
  },
  extraReducers: builder => {
    builder
      .addMatcher(isAnyOf(authError, loginFail, /* ... and so on */), resetAuth);
  },
});
```